# Excel Compare tables

Tags: excel, excel-2007, ms-office

I have 2 excel pivot tables with 2 columns but got different number of rows.

The first column of each table got and Number, and the column 2 got a value.

I want to compare both tables, finding the same Number on Column 1 for each table, and sum the values of column 2.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is copy and paste (as values) the pivot tables to a new sheet, then use vlookup to compare the values [Ref Vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx).  There are more complex and reusable solutions, but you would need to define if you want to use a macro, or other tools.